# Сортировка постов Wordpress с помощью плагина Post Views Counter

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Помогите пожалуйста, есть плагин подсчета просмотров, Post Views Counter, мне нужно с помощью этого плагина сделать сортировку постов по количеству просмотров. В документации к плагину дается такой код:

```
$args = array(
    'order' => 'asc',
    'post_type' => 'event'
);
$most_viewed = pvc_get_most_viewed_posts( $args );
```

В шаблоне моей темы вот такой цикл:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'content' );
endwhile;                       
the_posts_pagination();
else :
get_template_part( 'no-results' );
endif;
?>
```

Как правильно вставить этот код в цикл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код должен выглядеть примерно вот так:

```php
$args = [
    'order'     => 'asc',
    'post_type' => 'event',
];

$most_viewed = pvc_get_most_viewed_posts( $args );

if ( $most_viewed->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $most_viewed->have_posts() ) {
        $most_viewed->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content' );
    }

    the_posts_pagination();
} else {
    get_template_part( 'no-results' );
}

wp_reset_postdata(); // Important.
```